# How can I overload the assignment of a class member?

Tags: python, django, class, variable-assignment

I am writing a Player model class in Python with Django, and I've ran into a small problem with the password member. I'd like the password to be automatically hashed upon assignment, but I can't find anything about overloading the assignment operator or anything.  Is there any way I can overload the assignment of `password` so as to automatically do `hashlib.md5(password).hexdigest()` on it?

```
from django.db import models

class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    email = models.EmailField()
```

Comment: why don't you do it explicitly?

Comment: Because it's a pain, and the Django automatic admin won't do it.

Comment: pain? to add another line to your code? line that you already have.

Comment: @SilentGhost Why don't you just tell the line?

Comment: "Django automatic admin won't do it", and this is veering off topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can't you use properties and override setter for the field?

Citing from [django documentation](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/properties/):

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def _get_full_name(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

    def _set_full_name(self, combined_name):
        self.first_name, self.last_name = combined_name.split(' ', 1)

    full_name = property(_get_full_name)

    full_name_2 = property(_get_full_name, _set_full_name)
```

Comment: "Properties" is one of those odd bits of Python terminology that's challenging for newcomers to the language.  As Krzyk's example shows  you can create "getter" and "setter" functions (and "delete-er" functions as well) and when you bind a class attribute to the results of a call to "property()" (taking getter as a required argument and optional setter, and deleter) ... then all access to that attribute is now mediated by the property functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [HashedProperty](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/wiki/UsageRecipes/HashProperty) class that I created for SQLAlchemy. You can use with Django like this:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True)
    password_hash = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    password_salt = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    password = HashedProperty('password_hash', 'password_salt',
                   hashfunc=salted_hexdigest(hashlib.md5),
                   saltfunc=random_string(32))
    email = models.EmailField()
```